# I need help for many to many relation query

Tags: mysql

I have working on database for dictionary project. I have to store a word and meaning with `many to many` relationship.

Below I have mentioned the sample with my table structure. I hope the table structure is right, but I don't know how to select all meanings for single word while user searching.

And also I have to write a query to select all word and synonyms linked to a single meaning. And also I have to write a query to select all meaning and synonyms linked to a single word.

```
word_table  
+----+------+ 
| id | word | 
+----+------+ 
|  1 |  A   | 
|  2 |  B   | 
|  3 |  C   | 
+----+------+ 


meaning_table  
+----+--------+ 
| id | meaning| 
+----+--------+ 
|  1 |  X     | 
|  2 |  Y     | 
|  3 |  Z     | 
+----+--------+ 


word_meaning_table  
+---------+-----------+ 
| word_id | meaning_id| 
+---------+-----------+ 
|  1      |  1        | 
|  1      |  2        | 
|  1      |  3        | 
|  2      |  1        | 
|  2      |  3        | 
|  3      |  2        | 
|  3      |  3        | 
+---------+-----------+ 




   synonyms_table  
    +----+--------+ 
    | id | synonys| 
    +----+--------+ 
    |  1 |  aa    | 
    |  2 |  bb    | 
    |  3 |  cc    | 
    +----+--------+ 


    word_synonyms_table  
    +---------+-----------+ 
    | word_id | synonym_id| 
    +---------+-----------+ 
    |  1      |  1        | 
    |  1      |  2        | 
    |  1      |  3        | 
    +---------+-----------+
```

> Expected output should be like this.
>
> If user searching for a word "A" in word table the result should be

```
Result for word "A"
    +----+----------+---------+ 
    | word| meaning | synonys |
    +----+----------+---------+ 
    |  A |  X       | aa      |
    |  A |  Y       | bb      |
    |  A |  Z       | cc      |
    +----+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need many joins:

```
SELECT w.word,m.meaning,s.synonys
FROM word_table w
INNER JOIN word_meaning_table wm
 ON(w.id = wm.word_id)
INNER JOIN meaning_table m
 ON(wm.meaning_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN word_synonyms_table ws
 ON(w.id = ws.word_id)
INNER JOIN synonyms_table s
 ON(ws.synonym_id = s.id)
```

Let me reffer you to [this document](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) that explain all about join syntax's.

Comment: Wouldn't that INNER JOIN omit results completely when a word has e.g. no synonyms but only a meaning? I didn't test it but perhaps some of them should be LEFT JOINs.

Comment: @PerlDog Perhaps, not according to the data and output he provided, to the OP , if it is the case, and there can be missing info in some of the tables, replace the join to those tables from an inner join to a left join